# jQuery UI Tabs - Default Closed? How to make Collapsed on page load?

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it possible to make the UI Tabs closed by default, until clicked?
The 2 week search is still on!  Such a complex/bloated script, and yet no simple way to control

Comment: What do you mean by closed? The point of tabs is to have one displaying at all times

Comment: You are right @Kevin Bowersox . But i have a situation such i need to be closed by default.

Comment: Do you mean an accordion?

Comment: I know that Accordion can collapse. but i have to do the same with the jqueryUI tab. @LeeGunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could use some polish, but it should get you on the right track.

http://jsfiddle.net/vbmMJ/2/

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $(".tab-content").hide();
    $(".ui-tabs-active").removeClass("ui-tabs-active");
    $(".ui-state-active").removeClass("ui-state-active");
        $(".ui-tabs-anchor").click(function() {
            $($(this).attr("href") + " .tab-content").first().show();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
        <div class="tab-content">
            tab 1 content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        <div class="tab-content">
            tab 2 content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 18):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rakesh_vadnal/PmsCh/6/),

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
   collapsible: true,
   active: false
});
```

Comment: This is more proper way to do it.